# Formal definition of polynomial of several variables (or in several unknowns)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to make a formal definition of polynomial of several variables with coefficients in R a commutative ring.

For $1$ variable We can define a polynomial as every function $p:\mathbb{N}\to R$ with finite support $S$. As $ S=\{n\in\mathbb{N} : p(n) \neq 0\} $ is finite, it has a maximum, let's call it $k$, the degree of $p$.

And now We can represent (as usual) $p\equiv \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i x^i$ with $a_i=p(i)$ for all $i\in\{0,\ldots, n\}$.

For $2$ variables, $x_1$ and $x_2$ you can think about $p:\mathbb{N}^2\to R$ with finite support, and for example the polynomial $2+x_1-x_1x_2 + 4x_1^3$ would be $p(0,0)=2, p(1,0)=1, p(1,1)=-1, p(3,0)=4$, but We do not have the degree now so, ¿how can we write in sum form?¿It is correct my attempt?¿Can we generalize for $n$ variables?

Comment: You could define it inductively, $R[x_1,x_2]$ is the polynomial ring in $x_2$ over the ring $R[x_1]$

Comment: That's a really nice solution¡ Can we extend the sum form that way?

Comment: The only thing that changes is that the sum form becomes more complicated: you now have to sum over *ordered tuples of* natural numbers rather than individual natural numbers. But that's not a serious issue. (Alternatively as @TokenToucan says you can use an inductive approach, but that has its own limitations: we now need to bring in direct limits to talk about rings of functions in infinitely many indeterminates, whereas the approach above is really one-size-fits-all:

Comment: a polynomial over a set $X$ of indeterminates of arbitrary cardinality is just a map from $\{$finitely supported functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{N}\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, which is itself finitely supported. (The idea is that a finitely supported function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ $\approx$ a product of indeterminates $\prod_{x\in X}x^{f(x)}$.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to view a polynomial ring $R[x]$ or $R[x, y]$ and so on is as a *monoid algebra*. I won't explain exactly what that means, but to define a polynomial ring in $k$ variables, you would do it like this:

1. Regard $M = (\mathbb{N}^k, +)$ as a *commutative monoid* under point-wise addition, for instance if $k = 3$ we could have $(0, 1, 2) + (3, 4, 0) = (3, 5, 2)$.
2. Let $R[M]$ be the free $R$-module with basis given by $\{x^m \mid m \in M\}$. Here $x^m$ is just alterative notation for $m$, which proves notationally useful in what follows. At this point $R[M]$ is a free module with a basis, so we have linear combinations of basis elements, and can decide when things are linearly independent.
3. Equip $R[M]$ with an $R$-bilinear multiplication by defining for each $n, m \in M$ that $x^n x^m = x^{n + m}$. Now $R$ is a ring, we can check that $x^{(0, \ldots, 0)}$ functions as a unit element, and multiplication is commutative because $M$ is commutative.

Now I claim that $R[M]$ is the usual polynomial algebra in $k$ variables. For example, when $k = 3$ just following the definitions gives equations like
$$ \begin{aligned}
(2x^{(0, 0, 0)} + 3 x^{(0, 1, 2)})8 x^{(3, 5, 2)}
  &= 16x^{(3, 5, 2)} + 24 x^{(3, 6, 4)},
\end{aligned} $$
So the element $x^{(a, b, c)} \in R[M]$ behaves just like $x_1^a x_2^b x_3^c \in R[x_1, x_2, x_3]$.

If you want to write down the free module $R[M]$ in a different form there are many ways to do it, but finitely-supported functions $f \colon M \to R$ is a good way to do it. You can then interpret what the product of two such functions $f, g \colon M \to R$ are, by following the definitions through, to get something like

$$ (f \cdot_{R[M]} g)(p) = \sum_{\substack{m, n \in M \\ m + n = p}} f(m) g(n), $$

For example in the sum written above, to find the coefficient of $x^{(3, 5, 2)}$ on the right-hand side, I want to look at all the ways of finding $x^m$ and $x^n$ on different sides of the product such that $m + n = (3, 5, 2)$.